# how to make android.support.* available for import

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm trying to import `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer` into my project but with no luck. In fact, I can't even see the `support` folder. Using the Android SDK Manager what do I need to make sure is installed?

** EDIT **

I already have `Extras` > `Android Support Library` installed up to Rev. 20

I chacked in /extras/android/support and it exists on my file system

Comment: have you added the library to your project?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project right click -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

Comment: what I tend to use as a short-cut to add both the support-v4 library and the appcompat-v7 to my project is to create the project with a min SDK of 8 using Navigation Drawer. Eclipse sets up the build path perfectly fine and the Actionbar is ready to use without a hassle.